# I can't do connection with 3270 port

Tags: mainframe

I have just installed a mainframe emulator and I have problems for running it. I think the problem is my 3270 TCP port. Reading a guide I found somebody say that you can do this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3270
```

but when I try the answer is:

```
The connection to the host it can't be opened with port 3270 more or less 
(I have windows in spanish) . Error on the connection.
```

Do you know how can I get connection with this direction and this port?

Comment: You meed to talk to your network support people. It is possible, perhaps quite likely, that you should not be using telnet. The thing about taking stuff from the internet is that it may just be plain inappropriate for your site. Your security staff may have concerns about you just experimenting on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to eliminate issues with your 3270 emulator configuration by attempting to telnet to the mainframe from the PC. Again, if my understanding is correct, then you need to use

```
telnet <ip or hostname of the mainframe>
```

In your example, you are using the local loopback address.

It is unlikely that you should be using port 3270. 3270 connections are typically configured on port 23, which is the default telnet port.

If the connection to the mainframe is successful, you can input any character string in the terminal and then press Enter.

An error such as this:

```
IKJ56710I INVALID USERID,xxxx
```

Will validate the fact that the port is open and that your emulator issues are down to something other than network problems (probably local configuration).